# Hibernate won't load certain table under different OS

Tags: mysql, windows, linux, hibernate

I am using Hibernate and mySQL.

I develop the java application mostly on windows. All the tables are created with lowercase.

When I deployed it on the linux server, I noticed the tables are now in the proper casing (java naming convention). That's fine and all, but for some reason, one of my oneToMany List isn't loaded.

I am not using any other query except for ***"from "+class.getName()***

I have tried changing the ***lower_case_table_names=2*** in ***my.conf*** so it matches in windows, however that didn't help.

Any other ideas?

---

Actually, that was stupid. It was my logic in the application that caused the problem, I was looking to do some partial fetching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've selected the wrong option, a quote from the manual:
 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

> **lower_case_table_names =**
>   0
>   Table and database names are stored on disk using the lettercase specified in the CREATE TABLE or CREATE DATABASE statement. Name comparisons are case sensitive. You should not set this variable to 0 if you are running MySQL on a system that has case-insensitive file names (such as Windows or Mac OS X). If you force this variable to 0 with --lower-case-table-names=0 on a case-insensitive file system and access MyISAM tablenames using different lettercases, index corruption may result.
>
> 1
>   Table names are stored in lowercase on disk and name comparisons are not case sensitive. MySQL converts all table names to lowercase on storage and lookup. This behavior also applies to database names and table aliases.
>
> 2
>   Table and database names are stored on disk using the lettercase specified in the CREATE TABLE or CREATE DATABASE statement, but MySQL converts them to lowercase on lookup. Name comparisons are not case sensitive. **This works only on file systems that are not case sensitive!** InnoDB table names are stored in lowercase, as for lower_case_table_names=1.

Option 2 will never work on Linux, because that system is case-sensitive.
**On Linux and all other systems you need to use option 1.**

Then your case sensitivity problems will be over.

Comment: It turns out that I didn't need to do this step, because Hibernate handles it all for me. It was actually one of my update to the code that cause the problem. Thank you for your help.