# How to tell Hibernate annotation @Column to be case-sensitive?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, sybase

I'm trying to do a simple SELECT query in a table named ECM (**in uppercase**) on a Sybase db with Hibernate. I've annotated my DBO this way :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ECM")
public class RelationshipDbo {
    ...
}
```

However, I'm facing a "*table not found*" error : the generated SQL has the table name in lowercase. I cannot change the database configuration to tell it to be case-insensitive.

I've also tried putting quotes like this :

```
@Table(name="`ECM`")
```

and this :

```
@Table(name="'ECM'")
```

Result : the quotes are added in the query, but the table name is still converted from uppercase to lowercase.

Technical information :

```
Hibernate 4.3
JPA 1.2
org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect
```

Have you guys any idea?

**EDIT:** Also tried this [Hibernate changes @Table(name) to lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489932/hibernate-changes-tablename-to-lowercase)

Then my columns names and table name are automatically quoted, but the names still get lowercased.

Comment: Hi @Deathtiny, are you able to find the solution for this problem, I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

My goal is a little different since was trying to create tables upper case and hibernate created them in lower case. Also i was using MySQL not Sybase. 
But for me quoting the names like this worked:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"ECM\"")
public class RelationshipDbo {
    ...
}
```

Then tables were created upper case. Maybe that helps also for the queries.

Comment: Seems ugly but actually works.
However, best option would be to change Hibernate's naming strategy, @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39194169/956727

Answer (score 1):

I think I have your answer:

Basically, you need to change the naming strategy for you JPA provider. How you do this will depend on how you setup your project.

In my case, using spring boot data I set a property in my application.properties to

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```

Without more details from you I can't give more specifics on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use backticks as in `` @Table(name="`ECM`")? ``

This must work from Hibernate point. If not then problem should be in DB (if i'm not wrong)

Comment: Already tested it, and unsuccessful, as stated in my post. Problem is that, even quoted, the ECM letter get lowercased for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

What is your Sybase db version ? 
`SybaseDialect` has been deprecated in Hibernate 3.5 and then refactored since Hibernate 4.1 with a bunch of subclasses matching different versions of Sybase. Have you tried one of the subclasses to see if it makes any difference?

- org.hibernate.dialect.Sybase11Dialect
- org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseAnywhereDialect
- org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseASE15Dialect

Comment: Thanks, tried the three possible dialects, but the generated SQL stays the same: always my table name lowercased..

Comment: Strange. I ran a quick test by switching to SybaseDialect in an existing project (using an H2 in-mem db) and the case in my SQL output is correct.. The main difference I see in my config is that I'm using JPA 2.1. not sure if this makes a difference.