# Spring boot JPA insert in TABLE with uppercase name with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i have a table entity mapped as :

```
@Entity
public class ItemsToRegister implements Serializable{

@Id
@Column(name = "ID_ITEM_TO_REGISTER")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
.....
```

When i try to insert new record in database, the table name was translated in lowercase as : items_to_register , but my table name is ITEMS_TO_REGISTER
How can i fix my problem without change MySql configuration? (my.cnf)

I have in my application.properties file :

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

Answer (score 171, accepted):

On hibernate 5, it would be

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

in your **application.properties** file.

Comment: How to do with hibernate 3?

Answer (score 19):

As @jasonleakey suggested we can consider using naming-strategy as below.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

this tells Hibernate to generate SQL's as exactly as specified in the @Table (name=" ") or @Column(name=" "). All well.

But keep in mind - while using PhysicalNamingStrategy without @Table, @Column annotations in the entity class, hibernate generates SQL using class name and variable names.  Consider the below java class

```
Class Employee {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName; 
}
```

then the generated sql would be,

```
select employee0_.firstName,employee0_lastName from Employee employee0_;
```

Unfortunately this is not a great choice as typically we would have defined the columns in DB as FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME and table name as EMPLOYEE. Had you not used PhysicalNamingStrategy the SQL would have been

```
select employee0_.first_name,employee0_last_name from employee employee0_;
```

so it's really a choice between the below two options.

- Use PhysicalStrategy and explicitly define all tables names/column names in java code with @Table and @Column annotations.

  or
- Define lowercase table name in db and let hibernate automatically generate table names/column names for us.

Comment: I think the best approach is to alway use PhysicalNamingStrategy and explicitly define table names in lowercase @Table(name="name_in_lowercase"). And setup database to keep table names in lowercase (lower_case_table_names=1 in case of mysql).

Answer (score 16):

You'll need to escape the table name with tics(`) to make it case sensitive.

```
@Table(name = "`ITEMS_TO_REGISTER`")
```

Comment: The tics didn't work, but escaping a double quote did. ie. 
`@Table(name = "\"ITEMS_TO_REGISTER\"")`. I'm on postgres and using eclipselink. Maybe that makes a difference.

Comment: Yep, that's the proper way of doing it: with regular quotes (") as Josh C. pointed out. If hibernate sees those, it quotes the given identifier appropriately for the dialect e.g. with backticks (`) for MySQL.

Comment: Using forward slashes works, although it looks utterly disgusting.

Answer (score 11):

The solution is to add:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```

to `application.properties`

Answer (score 6):

You can implement your own strategy and invoke it from application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=com.proto.CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy
```

Bellow an example that always capitalize the first letter

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.Identifier;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment;

public class CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy implements PhysicalNamingStrategy, Serializable {
    /**
     * Singleton access
     */
    public static final CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy INSTANCE = new CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy();

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalCatalogName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return capitalize(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalSchemaName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return capitalize(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return capitalize(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalSequenceName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return capitalize(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return capitalize(name);
    }

    private Identifier capitalize(Identifier name) {
        if (name == null)
            return null;
        if (name.isQuoted())
            return name;
        String text = StringUtils.capitalize(name.getText());
        return Identifier.toIdentifier(text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use H2 database in the example.

Making table name "user" with backticks will give you lowercase table name in your database.

Entity class:

[image]

Table name in the database:

[image]

P.S. You can name entity as "User"(uppercase) it will give you "user"(lowercase) anyway

Source:
http://coddingbuddy.com/article/56566857/jpa-uppercase-table-names

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEMS_TO_REGISTER")
public class ItemsToRegister implements Serializable {
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this property:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        globally_quoted_identifiers: true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using yml configuration, add this:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```