# Spring Boot: Tables created with lowercase

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I'm using `Spring Boot` and `PostgreSQL` database. I have this entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")

public class Test {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
}
```

And here's my `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username = postgres
spring.datasource.password = 1234
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = 
org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
```

It creates table but the name of the table is `test` (with lowercase). How to make it uppercase?

Here's my `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

*EDIT*

By the way i'm getting the following error while installing the project with Maven (clean,install):

`java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at 
....................................
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not yet implemented
    at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:688) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob(PgConnection.java:1269) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
    ... 70 common frames omitted`

Is it somehow related?

Comment: @lucumt Accepted answer from that question didn't work for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796446/postgres-case-sensitivity read the comment and accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

You should try following ways:

1) Add to application application.properties `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical` so:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username = postgres
spring.datasource.password = 1234
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

2) Or try to change `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect` to `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username = postgres
spring.datasource.password = 1234
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

For more information, you should see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353492/jpa-uppercase-table-names/36398277) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571848/spring-boot-jpa-insert-in-table-with-uppercase-name-with-hibernate)

Comment: First approach didn't work. Maybe i have some mismatch in my pom.xml? Can you check it please i will post it now.

Comment: Second approach also didn't work. Table still is creating with lowercase.

Comment: Using both and scape my table name solved the error:
* spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl 
* spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

Scape table name (or fields) like this:
@Table(name = "\"TEST\"")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Table(name = "\"TEST\"")
```

In postgres:

> Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted
>   names are always folded to lower case. For example, the identifiers
>   FOO, foo, and "foo" are considered the same by PostgreSQL, but "Foo"
>   and "FOO" are different from these three and each other. (The folding
>   of unquoted names to lower case in PostgreSQL is incompatible with the
>   SQL standard, which says that unquoted names should be folded to upper
>   case. Thus, foo should be equivalent to "FOO" not "foo" according to
>   the standard. If you want to write portable applications you are
>   advised to always quote a particular name or never quote it.)

from docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html

Comment: Please expand your answer with some documentation or explanation, why something works/doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping your entity name witha double quotes like following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"TEST\"")
public class Test {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;
}
```

Or

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")
public class Test implements Serializable {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;
}
```

Comment: Both approaches didn't work. By the way i'm getting the error while installing the project via Maven (clean,install). Check the edit.

Comment: try injecting spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false in your application.properties file

Comment: I tried this approach and it also didn't work... Table is still beying created with lowercase...

Comment: LOL now it works. I added `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`  and  `@Table(name="\"Test\"")`. It's not working if omit one of them