# Spring Boot Data with Cassandra throws error while inserting with capital table name

Tags: java, spring, cassandra

I have this table in cassandra

> FileProcess_ErrorLog

I have mapped this table with class:

```
@Table("FileProcess_ErrorLog")

public class FileProcessErrorLog {

    @PrimaryKey
    private UUID FileProcessErrorLogId;
    private int FileProcessAuditLogId;
```

When I am trying to insert data into this table using the above class, I am getting this:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table fileprocess_errorlog
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:50) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.4.0.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.4.0.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.4.0.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:68) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.4.0.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.query(CqlTemplate.java:296) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
... 40 common frames omitted
```

Note that Cassandra table names are case-sensitive.
I think the error is because it converts the table name to all lower-case and that is why it can not find the table.

I have tried escaping the table name using `(backticks) as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571848/spring-boot-jpa-insert-in-table-with-uppercase-name-with-hibernate) answer suggested (I thought they could be using the same strategy.)

How can I insert data without changing table name.

Comment: Have you considered that you maybe have an unconfigured table? Uppercase is not your issue, see here - https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/ucase-lcase_r.html . Could you show us your configuration class and a table structure?

Comment: @Urosh T.  So, it is saying, the db stores table names in lower case. But that means I have to change the table names to lower case.

Comment: I don't think so, even if you have a `FileProcess_ErrorLog` table, it is later transformed to a `fileprocess_errorlog`. Do you have such a table created in your Cassandra?

Comment: Yes @Urosh, I have mentioned it in question.

Comment: Yes, but is it created in lowercase or uppercase? :) I just wanted to prove my point that it doesn't really matter, you can test with some simple queries

Comment: it was created in UpperCase.
The question is how can I pass the Table name, So it is interpreted as it is.