# Hibernate 6.1 JPA - Unable to resolve property: {id}

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-6.x

Good day everyone,
trying to upgrade Spring 5 to 6 as well as Hibernate from 5 to 6 versions.
Stumble upon an issue which I guess related to JPA and id casing.

We are using JpaRepository with mix of custom `@Query`'es, no XML configuration.

The problem we face is methods delivered from JpaRepository can't find ID of Domain Model, presumably due to casing issue. So for example `findById(String id)` doesn't work out of box.

Original Stack Trace

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to resolve property: {id}
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:321)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy188.findById(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to resolve property: {id}
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.getPropertyIndex(EntityMetamodel.java:878)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getPropertyIndex(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2826)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.AbstractBatchEntitySelectFetchInitializer.getPropertyIndex(AbstractBatchEntitySelectFetchInitializer.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.BatchEntityInsideEmbeddableSelectFetchInitializer.lambda$registerResolutionListener$0(BatchEntityInsideEmbeddableSelectFetchInitializer.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.AbstractFetchParentAccess.notifyResolutionListeners(AbstractFetchParentAccess.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.embeddable.AbstractEmbeddableInitializer.initializeInstance(AbstractEmbeddableInitializer.java:205)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.embeddable.internal.EmbeddableAssembler.assemble(EmbeddableAssembler.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.initializeIdentifier(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.resolveEntityKey(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.resolveKey(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityJoinedFetchInitializer.resolveKey(EntityJoinedFetchInitializer.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.coordinateInitializers(StandardRowReader.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.readRow(StandardRowReader.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:443)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.load(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.load(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.CollectionLoaderBatchKey.load(CollectionLoaderBatchKey.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1710)
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.lambda$initialize$3(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:617)
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:615)
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:813)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:1003)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:989)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:443)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleUniqueKeyEntityLoaderStandard.load(SingleUniqueKeyEntityLoaderStandard.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.loadByUniqueKey(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2798)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.loadByUniqueKey(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2790)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntitySelectFetchByUniqueKeyInitializer.initializeInstance(EntitySelectFetchByUniqueKeyInitializer.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.coordinateInitializers(StandardRowReader.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.readRow(StandardRowReader.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:443)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.load(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.load(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderDynamicBatch.load(SingleIdEntityLoaderDynamicBatch.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderDynamicBatch.load(SingleIdEntityLoaderDynamicBatch.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4416)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4406)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:590)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:563)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1244)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1232)
    at org.hibernate.loader.access.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.loader.access.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.lambda$load$1(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.loader.access.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.perform(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.loader.access.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:2336)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:2303)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy179.find(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findById(SimpleJpaRepository.java:316)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:288)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:390)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Example of our ID mappings in Domain Model

```java
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
 @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
 @JsonProperty("ID")
 @Column(name = "`ID`", length = 36)
 private String id;
```

We are using upperCase Database Column names with `ID`. I suppose the problem is JPA trying to look for `id` while we have `ID` there.
Making custom `findById(String id)` with `@Query` works fine, but not very eager to change ~200 repositories :) So hoping for better solution.

Tried making custom `findById()` but that's local fix, tried naming strategy with Uppercase, didn't worked.

Comment: Have you tried escaped double quotes instead of ticks, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571848/spring-boot-jpa-insert-in-table-with-uppercase-name-with-hibernate#comment61318428_28574416? In this question and the answers there is also something about naming strategies, might also help.