# spring data rest hibernate is lower casing all table names and ignores @Table("Name")

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am trying to use spring-data-rest with MySql with hibernate as the JPA provider.

I want the table names used in the query to match the simple name of the class; Nothing more. How do I achieve that?

I have tried all of the naming strategies and it seems to have no effect. In addition, I have added

```
@Table("Foo")
```

And it gets lowercased as well

Here is the error:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'TEST.worker' doesn't exist

Here is the entity:

```
@Entity
public class Worker {
    private Long id;
    private String givenName;
    private String familyName;
    private LocalDate dob;
    private String nationalId;
    private byte[] photo;

    public Worker() {
        this.id = Math.abs(new Random().nextLong());
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GivenName")
    public String getGivenName() {
        return givenName;
    }

    public void setGivenName(String givenName) {
        this.givenName = givenName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "FamilyName")
    public String getFamilyName() {
        return familyName;
    }

    public void setFamilyName(String familyName) {
        this.familyName = familyName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DOB")
    public LocalDate getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(LocalDate dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "NationalID")
    public String getNationalId() {
        return nationalId;
    }

    public void setNationalId(String nationalId) {
        this.nationalId = nationalId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "photo")
    public byte[] getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(byte[] photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }
}
```

My relevant config:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl = false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringNamingStrategy
```

Transitive dependencies from spring data:

```
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
```

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489932/hibernate-changes-tablename-to-lowercase) doesn't apply;

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive) post. It could be helpful.

Comment: Do either of the solutions provided in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571848/spring-boot-jpa-insert-in-table-with-uppercase-name) work for you?

Comment: Which Hibernate version do you use?

Comment: @Chatoyancy Yes, actually. I inadvertently stumbled on it myself but your link(s) work. Provided it as an answer if you want. I basically backtracked my way up the stack to figure out how it was coming to that table name and used some auto complete from intellij to get there. I didn't find it sooner because it seems I was asking the wrong question and it was leading me to answers related to the OS.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `SpringNamingStrategy` it uses the same values as the [ImprovedNamingStrategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html) from Hibernate (verify it [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.2.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/hibernate/SpringNamingStrategy.html)).

If you check the link for `ImprovedNamingStrategy` you will see that the default behavior for `tableName` is to lowercase any mixed case names, which seems to be your case.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered that and Changed it to the EJB strategy. Thanks!

Comment: You can also extends the strategy and simply change this behavior only, if EJB strategy doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: I had the same problem. Using spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571848/spring-boot-jpa-insert-in-table-with-uppercase-name-with-hibernate solved the problem