# Hibernate and Spring DataJPA can not handle Oracle table name with special character?

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When I used Spring datajpa and Hibenate to read Oracle, I met an error, I'll desc this:

1. The Oracle table name includes special character(double quotes), so, I have to use `SELECT * FROM "Graph" WHERE "ID"=1` .
2. So, when I use hibernate to write a entity class, I have to point its special name.

Here is the ddl which is used to create `"Graph"` table:

```
CREATE TABLE "ATLASCOPCO_TOOLSNET"."Graph" (
"ID" NUMBER(19) NOT NULL ,
"ResultID" NUMBER(19) NOT NULL ,
"GraphTypeID" NUMBER(19) NOT NULL ,
"SampleTime" BINARY_FLOAT NOT NULL ,
"AngleOffset" BINARY_FLOAT NOT NULL ,
"GraphValues" BLOB NOT NULL ,
"AngleFactor" BINARY_DOUBLE NULL ,
"TorqueFactor" BINARY_DOUBLE NULL ,
"StartTime" BINARY_FLOAT NULL ,
"EndTime" BINARY_FLOAT NULL 
)
LOGGING
NOCOMPRESS
NOCACHE
```

When I used the normal table name like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Graph")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Graph {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID\"")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ResultID")
    private Long resultId;

    @Column(name = "GraphTypeID")
    private Long graphTypeID;

    @Column(name = "SampleTime")
    private BINARY_FLOAT sampleTime;

    @Column(name = "AngleOffset")
    private BINARY_FLOAT angleOffset;

    @Column(name = "GraphValue")
    private byte[] graphValue;

    @Column(name = "AngleFactor")
    private BINARY_DOUBLE angleFactor;

    @Column(name = "TorqueFactor")
    private BINARY_DOUBLE torqueFactor;

    @Column(name = "StartTime")
    private BINARY_FLOAT startTime;

    @Column(name = "EndTime")
    private BINARY_FLOAT endTime;
}
```

I got error:`Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00972: identifier is too long`

When I used this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"Graph\"")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Graph {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "\"ID\"\"")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "\"ResultID\"")
    private Long resultId;

    @Column(name = "\"GraphTypeID\"")
    private Long graphTypeID;

    @Column(name = "\"SampleTime\"")
    private BINARY_FLOAT sampleTime;

    @Column(name = "\"AngleOffset\"")
    private BINARY_FLOAT angleOffset;

    @Column(name = "\"GraphValue\"")
    private byte[] graphValue;

    @Column(name = "\"AngleFactor\"")
    private BINARY_DOUBLE angleFactor;

    @Column(name = "\"TorqueFactor\"")
    private BINARY_DOUBLE torqueFactor;

    @Column(name = "\"StartTime\"")
    private BINARY_FLOAT startTime;

    @Column(name = "\"EndTime\"")
    private BINARY_FLOAT endTime;
}
```

I got `Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character`

Comment: Your query does equal to `SELECT * FROM Graph WHERE ID=1`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13568581

Answer (score 0):

Remove the special character `\"` in column names, it is causing the issue. JPA and Oracle driver will handle all correctly.

You can omit the `"`, ANSI SQL does work too.

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE (ID NUMBER(19) NOT NULL , NAME VARCHAR2(19) NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's Say you have a Column in a table whose name is **"id"** as shown below:

[image: "id"]

Then to use the special character (**"**) you need to add an escape sequence as below:

```
    @Column(name="`\"id\"`")
    private int id;
```

The result will be a column with name as (**"id"**).
Please find the below updated Graph POJO class:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table (name="`\"Graph\"`")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Graph {
@Id
@Column (name="`\"ID\"`")
private Long id;

@Column (name="`\"ResultID\"`")
private Long resultId;

@Column(name="`\"GraphTypeID\"`")
private Long graphTypeID;

@Column (name="`\"SampleTime\"`")
private BINARY_FLOAT sampleTime; 

@Column (name="`\"AngleOffset\"`")
private BINARY_FLOAT angleOffset;

@Column (name="`\"GraphValue\"`")
private byte[] graphValue;

@Column (name="`\"AngleFactor\"`")
private BINARY_DOUBLE angleFactor;

@Column (name="`\"TorqueFactor\"`")
private BINARY_DOUBLE torqueFactor;

@Column (name="`\"StartTime\"`")
private BINARY_FLOAT startTime;

@Column (name="`\"EndTime\"`")
private BINARY_FLOAT endTime;
}
```

---

To retrieve the data from your Graph table use below code in Hibernate:

```
Query query=session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM `\" Graph \"` WHERE `\"ID\"`=1 ");
```

Hope this helps you.